# Auth0 (auth0.com) OIDC and user decomissionning with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, auth0

We are using Auth0 (https://www.auth0.com) with the OIDC compliant authorization code grant flow for our web app. We have an integration with a Azure AD which works fine (login, logout works)

My question is:

How would you implement in Auth0 user decommissioning (user removal) such that when a user is removed from the Azure AD, then within a reasonable amount of time (ex: 6 hours), the SilentLogin fails (when requesting a new access token) ?

Additional Info: Keep in mind that the user might have already logged in and has a valid website cookie. How to you make sure that the next call to an API fails when that user is removed from Azure AD?

Comment: If I understand correctly,  you cannot sign  with the user's credential which was removed from Azure AD immediately.  The massage that shows the user is not in the direcotry will shows in the login page.